# Fallout shelter. Baby boys?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My vault dwellers haven't been able to give birth to any male babies. I've had about 10 pregnancies but they all were girls.

I'm wondering if this caused by a bug in the game or is it just based on luck?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is just a matter of probability.
The probability to get children of only one gender is (1/2)<sup>10</sup> which is 1/2<sup>10</sup> which is 1 in 1024, which is about 1 tenth of a percent (~ 0.1%). Not really impossible, only unlikely.

Comment: That seems incredibly high. do you have a source?

Comment: @Ben A source for what? The probability of a set of independent events being the individual probabilities multiplied together?

Comment: @Ben. Are you asking for a source that babies have a 1/2 chance of being male, or are you asking for a source that getting 10 female babies in a row has a chance of 1/1024?

Comment: Ok, I misread that. The answer is a little unclear in it's subject matter (out of context), so I made the assumption it was the chance of getting a baby boy.